# override standard action with Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created a new tab for a custom object and now want to override the standard new/edit actions to open a custom lightning web component I have created. I have got the standard detail action to open my custom lightning web component. But I cannot work out how to override the action when clicking the new button or clicking the edit record button. I have found the action override screen in setup under the object manager but my lightning web component does not show as an option?

Any links on how to do this? I'm guessing it is something I am missing in the components XML targets file but I've gone through all the documentation and can't see what it could be.

Answer (score 5):

You can not directly override action with Lightning web component directly. You need to call your component in Aura Component and use that aura component to override the action.

Aura interfaces that are not listed don’t currently have an equivalent in Lightning Web Components.

1. lightning:hasPageReference
2. flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes
3. flexipage:availableForRecordHome
4. force:hasRecordId
5. force:hasSObjectName
6. forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes
7. clients:availableForMailAppPage
8. clients:availableForMailAppPage

Read here:- [Migrate Interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_interfaces)

You can read here how to use Lightning Web Component in aura component :- [Compose Aura Components from Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition)

Answer (score 3):

1. When you want to use in record home pages, app pages etc, you need to use in `Lightning App Builder`. You can configure [meta file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_app_builder)
2. Action overrides are not yet available. You can refer to [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/get_started_supported_experiences) reguarly to check what all features are available at any point of time.

---

**Supported Salesforce Experiences and Tools**

Lightning web components are supported in many Salesforce experiences and tools. To use a Lightning web component with an unsupported experience or tool, wrap it in an Aura component.

These Salesforce experiences and tools are supported.

- Lightning Experience
- Salesforce Mobile App
- Lightning App Builder
- Experience Builder sites
- Experience Builder
- Standalone Apps
- Utility Bars
- Flows
- Quick Actions in Lightning Experience
- Custom Tabs
- Gmail and Outlook integration
- Embedded Service Chat
- Lightning Components for Visualforce
- Lightning Out (beta)
- First-Generation Managed Packages
- Second-Generation Managed Packages
- Service Cloud Voice Toolkit API
- Unlocked Packages
- Unmanaged Packages
- Change Sets
- Metadata API—LightningComponentBundle
- Tooling API—LightningComponentBundle, LightningComponentResource
- EMP API

---

**Unsupported Experiences and Tools**

Lightning Web Components doesn’t currently support these Salesforce experiences and tools. To use a Lightning web component with these experiences and tools, wrap the component in an Aura component.

- Salesforce Console APIs (Navigation Item API, Workspace API, Utility Bar API)
- URL Addressable Tabs
- Conversation Toolkit API, Omni Toolkit API, Quick Action API
- Standard Action Overrides, Global Actions, List View Actions, Related List View Actions
- Chatter Extensions